# use MicroLink with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am building a link preview and I want to get the input from a user then display it with MicroLink, the problem that every time i want to get the link i get 'Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL'

```
import Microlink from '@microlink/react'
import React from 'react'
export default class LinkPreviewer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            url:'https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-preventdefault'

        }
        this.handelChange = this.handelChange.bind(this)
    }
    handelChange(e){
        console.log(e)
        this.setState({
            url:e.target.value
        })
    }            

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
          
         <input type='text' name='url' value={this.state.url} onChange={this.handelChange}/> 
           
               
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>
           <Microlink
                 url={this.url}
               />
              
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the issue ? and please format well the beginning of your code !

Comment: the issue is that i can't display the link the user give to me  and i always get :Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.url` doesn't exist, it's `this.state.url`, so you need to replace your code by this :

```
<Microlink
   url={this.state.url}
/>
```